# Can Office 365 admin read emails of a Gmail account connected to Outlook

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office, exchange-server

I have an Office 365 account assigned to me by my employer. I use Outlook app on my Mac to access the emails.

If I connect my Gmail account to the Outlook desktop app, will my Exchange Admin / Office 365 admin be able to read my Gmail inbox?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, of course, if you don't provide physical access to your Outlook app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eugene. Any idea if the same applies for data shared on MS Cloud?